# Can I build my app into the standard Android camera application?

Tags: android

I am new in mobile app dev. And I want to build my app in standard camera. It will be like helper guide lines on camera to make better photos. But I don't want to build separate app, instead I want make it in standard cam like add on. So, because I am new in that sphere, I don't know is it possible to do, and which API or tools I should use. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the way you want to achieve this based on description above : **no, you can't.**

Only way to do something like this is build own app (with own app icon in launcher) and try open camera from your app by `Intent`, but before that show tutorial within your app. But it seems to be not nice idea for tutorial purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add more features in the application provided by different vendors. Each vendor(like Samsung, HTC) has its own application of Camera which is protected. If you want to do that then you will need to have permission of a vendor or become a vendor in the process. That entails to building your own OS or custom OS (Android Source Code is Open Source).

Next best thing you could do is provide a helper application that gives tips and tricks and anything informative for guidelines. Then user can learn from your app which is available for download through Google Play.

It is worth noting that almost every device hardware is different. Some features are device specific. Therefore quality and settings will also differ.